# Efficient multi window tkinter

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter

So I am writing this code with multiple states where each state is represented with its own Tkinter window. the question is how to do this efficiently knowing that each window is defined as a class on a separate file. I'm doing this right now but I'm not sure this okay as the interface seems to be lagging compared to when I launch the class directly (not from the method call)

```
def StartExperimentButtonCallback(self):
        ErrorMessage=''
        #build error message    
        if(len(ErrorMessage)>0):
            ErrorMessage += '\n'
            messagebox.showerror("Error", ErrorMessage)
        else:
            self.parent.destroy()

            factory = eego_sdk.factory()

            v = factory.getVersion()
            print('version: {}.{}.{}.{}'.format(v.major, v.minor, v.micro, v.build))

            print('delaying to allow slow devices to attach...')
            time.sleep(1)

            amplifier=factory.getAmplifiers()

            amplifier=amplifier[0]
            
            root = tk.Tk()
            # This is the section of code which creates the main window
            root.geometry('1280x740')
            root.configure(background='#FFFFFF')
            root.title('Impedances')
            timer = ImpedanceGUI(root, amplifier, self.SubjectID.get(), [float(self.RightSphere.get()),float(self.LeftSphere.get()),float(self.RightCylinder.get()), float(self.LeftCylinder.get())])
            del self
            root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `time.sleep()` is the culprit.

Comment: `time.sleep()` freezes the whole script and achieves nothing

Comment: @Matiiss time.sleep() is only there for hardware preparation (EEG Amplifier) which I'm also doing even in the non-transition runs